# Getting a motorcycle license in France

Tags: france, driving-licenses, motorcycles

In order to obtain a motorcycle license in France (permis A1 for example), must one necessarily possess a car driver's license? Is there any way to legally drive motorcycles in France without having already obtained a car driver's license?

Comment: There is something strange about this question. **No, you cannot drive a motorcycle without a motorcycle license which is independent of a car license!** You need at least 7 hours in a french driving school on several days to get a A1 license and you must pass a theoretical and practical exam **and your home country does not need to accept the license**! This is not really a travel question, more for expatriates. And it sounds like the typical rip-off where people who are barred driving try to get the EU license to circumvent the prohibition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all. An A1 or A2 permit doesn't require to get a B permit first, or later. I've known people who got their A1 permit way before they B permit, and even one guy who never got his B permit, as he wasn't interested in driving cards.

Comment: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/N530